# Gem install wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

When I run `bundle`, I get the following:

```
-bash: bundle: command not found
```

I'm not a ruby developer, but it seems like I need bundler to get some software running other people wrote. So I'm trying to get bundler using `gem install bundler`, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1)
```

Using `--backtrace`

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1)
        /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/psych-4.0.1/lib/psych.rb:323:in `safe_load'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/safe_yaml.rb:31:in `safe_load'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:496:in `block (2 levels) in read_checksums'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:495:in `wrap'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:495:in `block in read_checksums'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:116:in `seek'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:494:in `read_checksums'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:547:in `block (2 levels) in verify'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:29:in `new'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:546:in `block in verify'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package/file_source.rb:30:in `open'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package/file_source.rb:30:in `with_read_io'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:545:in `verify'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:526:in `spec'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/source/local.rb:49:in `block in load_specs'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/source/local.rb:43:in `each'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/source/local.rb:43:in `load_specs'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/source/local.rb:83:in `find_gem'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:141:in `find_all'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:56:in `add_always_install'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:478:in `resolve_dependencies'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:194:in `install_gem'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:255:in `block in install_gems'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:251:in `each'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:251:in `install_gems'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:158:in `execute'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command.rb:313:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:173:in `process_args'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:143:in `run'
        /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:59:in `run'
        /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

- ruby version:
  `ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [arm-linux-gnueabihf]`.
- gem version:
  2.7.6.2
- I'm on a raspbian linux.

Comment: Not sure if something like `rvm` or `rbenv` works on Rapberry PI, but if it does, try installing a ruby via one of those instead of using the system ruby

Comment: It looks like you may have a version incompatibility between Psych and Ruby, if there is a line in your Gemfile relating to Psych, try removing it as it should come with Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

Psych Gem was the culprit in my case; uninstalling psych before running any bundler/gem commands fixed it for me:

Before:

```sh
$ bundle update rails
[SNIP]
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1)
An error occurred while installing activesupport (6.0.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '6.0.4.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.


$ gem install activesupport -v '6.0.4.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' --backtrace
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1)
        /home/local/PDC01/swi/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/psych-4.0.1/lib/psych.rb:323:in `safe_load'
        /home/local/PDC01/swi/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/safe_yaml.rb:31:in `safe_load'
[SNIP]
```

Fix:

```
$ gem uninstall psych

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. psych-3.3.0
 2. psych-4.0.1
 3. All versions
> 3
```

After:

```
...

$ gem install activesupport -v '6.0.4.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' 

Successfully installed activesupport-6.0.4.1
Parsing documentation for activesupport-6.0.4.1
```

Comment: I had the same problem where both psych v3 an psych v4 were installed, and I merely needed to uninstall psych v4 to get things working. Thanks!

Comment: In case you get a message like `gem "psych" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem`, you can also remove the gem itself via `rm -rf vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/psych-4.0.3` (changing this path to wherever it's installed to on your system)

Answer (score 2):

Running `gem update --system` should fix things since recent RubyGems versions should be compatible with both Psych 3 and Psych 4.