# gem update showing permission errror on WSL2

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I want to install jekyll on WSL2 as per [doc](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/). But get errors.

```
gem update
Updating installed gems                                                            
Updating fiddle                                                                    
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)                             
You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.5.0 
directory.
```

After `--backtrace`

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.5.0 directory.
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/installer.rb:706:in `verify_gem_home'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/installer.rb:854:in `pre_install_checks'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/installer.rb:281:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:97:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:168:in `block in install'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:156:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:156:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:409:in `install'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:213:in `update_gem'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:225:in `block in update_gems'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:224:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:224:in `update_gems'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:100:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command.rb:313:in `invoke_with_build_args'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:173:in `process_args'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:143:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:59:in `run'
/usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I have read [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68899508/gem-install-wrong-number-of-arguments-given-4-expected-1)  related que but they did not work.

System info:

1. `ruby -v`
   ruby 2.5.8p224 (2020-03-31 revision 67882) [x86_64-linux-
   gnu]
2. `gem -v`
   2.7.6.2
3. Distro - Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
4. Winver - Version 21H2 (OS build 22000.556)

   **EDIT:**

    output of  `gem environment`

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/commands/environment_command.rb:154: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.8 (2020-03-31 patchlevel 224) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/raghav/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.5
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/raghav/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.5.0
     - /home/raghav/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.5.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
     - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/raghav/.local/bin
     - /home/raghav/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /usr/lib/wsl/lib
     - /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath
     - /mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32
     - /mnt/c/WINDOWS
     - /mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
     - /mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
     - /mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/
     - /mnt/c/Users/Raghav/Downloads/cmake-3.20.3-windows-x86_64/cmake-3.20.3-windows-x86_64/bin
     - /mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/
     - /mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn/
     - /mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/Client SDK/ODBC/170/Tools/Binn/
     - /mnt/c/msys64/mingw64/bin"
     - /mnt/c/Users/Raghav/.dotnet/tools
     - /mnt/c/Users/Raghav/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
     - /mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_321/bin
     - /mnt/c/Users/Raghav/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/
     - /snap/bin
```

username : raghav

 root is the owner of files.

Comment: What is the output of `gem environment`? There should be some good diagnostic info there. What is your username? Who _owns_ `/var/lib/gems/2.5.0`? Who has write access to `/var/lib/gems/2.5.0`?

Comment: @jaredBeck I have attached output of `gem environment`. I want to add one more thing , `which ruby ` and `which gem` both shows  `/usr/bin/ruby` and `/usr/bin/gem ` respectively .

Comment: I was looking for `gem environment` warning .I got [git](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1426) but i am not able to make sense .

Answer (score 2):

The program you're trying to run attempts to perform privileged operations with an unprivileged account. `gem` will try to write to root owned directories even though you're running that as an unprivileged user. There's another problem which is `bundler` that will use `gem` which will therefore bring you to the same problem but this time you can't use the `--user-install` flag anymore. To overcome the default behavior without affecting the underlying operational system you can force gem to use a user account and bundler to use a local directory.

TL;DR:

What you need to do is use `gem install --user-install` instead of `gem install`. That will install gems to `~/.local/share/gem/`;

And `bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle'` or a similar command for every project. Alternatively, you can use `bundle config set --global path ~/.local/share/gem/`, which will use the same folder that `gem install --user-install` uses (On Ubuntu 22.04).

---

First of all, the current instructions on that tutorial suggests opening power shell and running `bash`. That is outdated. If you're using the Ubuntu App from Windows Store, when you run that App you'll get a shell inside the Ubuntu virtual machine, that's what you should use. From there you can follow the [ubuntu instructions](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/ubuntu/).

This is a step by step which works in this environment, it will use `sudo` only once where it is unavoidable:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential zlib1g-dev
$ gem install --user-install bundler jekyll webrick
```

With just that you can already use Jekyll inside Ubuntu as usual. If you want to use it from bundler, then you'll have to install webrick gem again because jekyll will overwrite Gemfile. Also, by default, bundler tries to install system-wide, so you'll have to configure it to use a local directory.

WARNING: only run these commands inside the directory of your blog, or a new empty directory for a future blog.

```bash
~$ sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential zlib1g-dev
~$ gem install --user-install bundler
~$ mkdir blog
~/blog$ cd blog
~/blog$ bundle init
~/blog$ bundle add jekyll
~/blog$ bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle'
~/blog$ bundle exec jekyll new --force --skip-bundle .
~/blog$ bundle add webrick
~/blog$ bundle install
```

Test it with `bundle exec jekyll serve`

If you're ok with using your user-wide gem folder and is aware that updating jekyll will update the version of the gems it depends, affecting your other ruby projects, then you can use the user-wide approach:

```bash
~$ sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential zlib1g-dev
~$ gem install --user-install bundler
~$ bundle config set --global path ~/.local/share/gem
~$ mkdir blog
~/blog$ cd blog
~/blog$ bundle init
~/blog$ bundle add jekyll
~/blog$ bundle exec jekyll new --force --skip-bundle .
~/blog$ bundle add webrick
~/blog$ bundle install
```

Of course, you can always use the system-wide approach too, which is the least recommended because it'll break your ruby installation:

```bash
~$ sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential zlib1g-dev
~$ sudo gem install bundler jekyll webrick
```

Comment: How do you get `gem update --system` to work.
e.g. I get error `sass-embedded requires RubyGems version >= 3.3.22` so need to update `gem update --system`

Comment: @DarVar if you're using a local install like my answer suggests, you'd use `gem update --user-install` instead.